# Can uuid4 collide when generated by python processes on different kubernetes pods

Tags: python, random, uuid

When having replicas of the same pod with a single container running a single python process on kubernetes, will each python process still generate `uuid.uuid4()` ids that are practically unique across the all pods or can it happen that 2 python processes are using the same seed when calling the `os.urandom` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.urandom() method is used to generate a string of size random bytes suitable for cryptographic use or we can say this method generates a string containing random characters. The probability of setting the same seed with os.urandom() is extremely low.

You should be safe ;)

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality

https://jhall.io/archive/2021/05/19/what-are-the-odds/

> To demonstrate how trivial the issue of UUID collision is, let’s consider some other things that are more likely to occur which may impact your team, but which also often get less attention:
>
> - 1 in 2.71 x 10<sup>18</sup>: Two random v4 UUIDs collide
> - 1 in 7.87 x 10<sup>9</sup>: Melinda French Gates divorces you and takes a portion of your business assets
> - 1 in 1.10 x 10<sup>7</sup>: Your most senior colleague dies in an airplane accident in the next 12 months, before documenting their work
> - 1 in 2.02 x 10<sup>5</sup>: Your data center is destroyed by a nuclear strike
> - 1 in 2.6 x 10<sup>3</sup>: Your boss resigns tomorrow
> - 1 in 1 x 10<sup>2</sup>: You suffer data loss due to disk or SSD failure
> - 1 in 1 x 10<sup>1</sup>: Your laptop and its data are stolen
>
> Technically speaking, UUID collision can happen. But even for critical applications, the odds are so low as to be dwarfed by the odds of truly catastrophic events, like nuclear war. This means most of us will get a much better ROI on our thinking time by focusing on problems that actually affect our businesses.